# React Native Android run causes "Illegal number of arguments for updateHotspot command"

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am creating a simple app using `React Native` for both `iOS` and `Android`. I've tested both platforms for a while and all works very well. But recently, I was focusing on `iOS` and all my functionalities are working perfectly so far. But when I tried it on `Android`; specifically when I tried to add an item to my existing local data in `AsyncStorage` it gives me the following error:

```
illegal number of arguments for updateHotspot command
```

My app has also other functions that ads item using `AsyncStorage` with no problem. But again everything works fine in `iOS`.

I'm using `Genymotion` (trial version) to test it in an `Android` platform.

I tried to search on the Internet but found nothing. It seems to me it's a `Java` thing.

**Update**:

I am no longer using Genymotion (trial version expired) but just the emulator from Android Studio this time.

This is the error that I received:

[image]

Comment: You might want to check <app_path>/android/settings.gradle and <app_path>/android/app/build.gradle for correct initialization.

Comment: Based on React Android's code, the event is related to mouse hover. This could be related to your OS on which you test your application with Genymotion. Someone suggested to try to run Genymotion in a VM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809568/how-to-get-mouseover-event-from-android-emulator

Comment: @Syl My Gennymotion trial version now expires but it was ran by in a VM (I used VirtualBox) however it has the same error. Outside Genymotion, I also tested on my own Android phone using Expo and also using Android studio but it has the same problem.

Comment: @JagjotSingh How do I know that I have the correct initialization? Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @Edper you'll need to refer each plugin's setup read-me to ensure you are following it correctly.

Comment: Are you sure it's from `AsyncStorage`? I searched in React Native code and it looks like the problem is coming from a `TouchableNativeFeedback` component (probably with a `TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple` background).

Comment: Or it could be from a library you use. For example: https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/issues/16

Comment: When you add your item to `AsyncStorage` what UI element are you using?

Comment: @mihai1990 I am not saying it's the AsyncStorage. In fact I am ruling it out because it's working on other part as I mentioned above. Sorry, if my construction of my sentence confuses you.

Comment: @inner_class7 I am using `TouchableOpacity`. But I used the same element on the other part of my code and it has not this same kind of error.

Comment: @Edper, Is that the entire stack trace in the screenshot? If not, can you show the entire stack trace?

Comment: That's everything that it shows. When I clicked each of those lines above, it doesn't show more details.

Comment: @Edper, Does the error disappear if you don't set `TouchableOpacity`'s onPress or set it to a empty function? If I understand correctly the error appears when you press that `TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: I removed the `onPress` completely with the same error.

Comment: @Edper, It's hard to say what the problem is without seeing the code. I assume it comes from one of the libraries in your project that uses `UIManager.dispatchViewManagerCommand(...)`. Try to find which one is by searching for `dispatchViewManagerCommand` in `node_modules` directory.

Comment: its nothing more than you are missing some implementaion command in your gradle and also not writing the command of project exporting in your setting.gradle!     simply try react-native link if that could do that automatically else type manually and this should go away!

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned you have other features in the application which seem to work perfectly fine in ios built of your application but on android side it causes you the bug! this bug is mostly **relevant** to

> **Missing** some **implementation command** in your **gradle** and also not writing the command of project **exporting in your setting.gradle**! simply try `react-native link` if that could do that automatically else type manually and this should go away!

**What is React Native link to me han?**

wellReact native link  tries to bind your Lib's configuration to both ios and android native code! its some time needed for some libraries/3rd party code and some time not!

It specifically targets in android system to have! exported modules in settings.gradle; along side your app level build.gradle to have implementation in dependencies and also links the library main module to your MyApplication file in java.

but here is a gotcha sometime it does not do! I think due to some poor or low standard coded libraries (no offence)! and some time process needs extra care so **instead of relying on linking** people like to **go for manually linking !** NATIVE CODE IS TRICKY in this kind of nature you know.

bottom line

try linking! or do it manually! read the docs of last library you added before falling into a pit hole like this ! Especially in android side of the code!

Answer (score 1):

Missing Certain Command Implementation in your Gradle.

Just try ==>

```
react-native link
```

Also I wanna tell you what is react native link

==>

React-native link is an automatic way for installing native dependencies. It is an alternative to manually linking the dependency in your project. It works for both Android and iOS