# Illegal number of arguments for 'updateHotspot' command error while calling focus method of TouchableHighlight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a TV app in React Native and am trying to manually trigger a focus on a TouchableHighlight. My code is:

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focus = this.focus.bind(this);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
  }

  focus() {
    this.buttonRef.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight ref={this.buttonRef} />
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever the focus methodd is called, I get the error: `Illegal number of arguments for 'updateHotspot' command`. How do I solve this?

Comment: [React Native Android run causes “Illegal number of arguments for updateHotspot command”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48462624/608639).

Comment: @khateeb did you manage to solve this?